# VBA Pivot Table Datafield Orientation Needs to be Flipped

Tags: excel, orientation, pivot-table, vba

My current code causes my data fields to return as rows rather than columnar. My goal is to make make the data fields have the columnar orientation.

```
Set objtable = Sheets(Worksheets.Count).PivotTableWizard

    Set objfield = objtable.PivotFields("Asset ID")
        objfield.Orientation = xlRowField

    Set objfield = objtable.PivotFields("Date")
        objfield.Orientation = xlColumnField

    Set objfield = objtable.PivotFields("Landmark")
        objfield.Orientation = xlPageField

    Set objfield = objtable.PivotFields("Charge")
        objfield.Orientation = xlDataField
        objfield.Function = xlSum

    Set objfield = objtable.PivotFields("Arrival Date")
        objfield.Orientation = xlDataField
        objfield.Function = xlMinenter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the Pivot table version. The following code can help solve your issue, when you create the pivot use the version 12 that is `xlPivotTableVersion12`.

```
DesWorkBk.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=sourcedataStr, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
       TableDestination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable2"
```